# Cursor appears for a flash when you hover even when cursor: none;

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I am trying to make a custom cursor using js (let's not discuss my terrible js). I set cursor: none for the html tag as well as in *:hover. This should make it so that the cursor is never visible. However, when you quickly hover over a link, the pointer flashes and you can see it for a split second. How do I fix this?

Here's a codepen showing the issue.
https://codepen.io/jacobyoon/pen/GPJdNQ

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="cursor"></div>
     <a href="#">Link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
  cursor: none;
}
*:hover {
  cursor:none;
}
a {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cursor {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

JS

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', cursor);
var $win = $(window);
var _cursor = document.getElementById('cursor');

function everyTick() {
    cursor();
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 0);
}

function getX(event) //left position
{
    if(!event.pageX)
    {
        return event.clientX;
    }
        else
    {
        return event.pageX - (document.body.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft);
    }
}

function getY(event) //top position
{
    if(event.pageY)
    {
        return event.pageY - (document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop);
    }
        else
    {
        return event.clientY;
    }
}

var offset = 5;

function cursor() {
    _cursor.style.top = getY(event) - 4 + "px";
    _cursor.style.left = getX(event) - 4 + "px";
    _cursorFollower.style.top = getY(event) - offset + "px";
    _cursorFollower.style.left = getX(event) - offset + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
* {
  cursor:none !important;
}
```

Basically when you apply `cursor: none` to the `HTML` element, this only takes precedence when another element doesn't have a cursor style - in the case of `a` elements, just about every browser has the style `cursor: pointer`.

This below code only takes effect when an element is hovered offer, which is what is causing that small delay.

```
*:hover {
  cursor:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out just doing this works.

```
a {cursor: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this `<a href="#" style="cursor:none">Link</a>` in your html file.

```js
window.addEventListener('mousemove', cursor);
var $win = $(window);
var _cursor = document.getElementById('cursor');

function everyTick() {
    cursor();
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 0);
}

function getX(event) //left position
{
    if(!event.pageX)
    {
        return event.clientX;
    }
        else
    {
        return event.pageX - (document.body.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft);
    }
}

function getY(event) //top position
{
    if(event.pageY)
    {
        return event.pageY - (document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop);
    }
        else
    {
        return event.clientY;
    }
}

var offset = 5;

function cursor() {
    _cursor.style.top = getY(event) - 4 + "px";
 _cursor.style.left = getX(event) - 4 + "px";
    _cursorFollower.style.top = getY(event) - offset + "px";
    _cursorFollower.style.left = getX(event) - offset + "px";
}
```

```css
html {
  cursor: none;
}

html *:hover {
  cursor: none;
}

a {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#cursor {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="cursor"></div>
     <a href="#" style="cursor:none">Link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```